# Unable to add a migration for second Db Context in Razor Pages project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

[The command to add Migration and Error that occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpCtm.png)

I have added the Connection string in the AppSetting.json file And Registered the Context in Program.cs.
I am Unable to use migration on second dbContext first migration was done fine.

Appsetting.json File:

```
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "RazorlistContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Razorlist.Data;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "RazorEmployeeContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Razorlist.Data;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

Program.cs File:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RazorlistContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorlistContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'RazorlistContext' not found.")));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<RazorlistContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorEmployeeContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'RazorEmployeeContext' not found.")));
```

Comment: check whether you have selected the right project as the startup and default project in the package manager console

Comment: How can i check it?

Comment: `Database=Razorlist.Data` is your database name? Why the name is like this? In addition, in your `program.cs` file you should initialize two dbContext service as well.

Comment: You can also try `Add-Migration init -context RazorEmployeeContext`. try `context` in loweer case and then `Update-Database -context RazorEmployeeContext`

Comment: Not sure, why the both database name are same `Razorlist.Data`

Comment: Razorlist is the project name and data is the folder where DB context classes reside for both contexts

Comment: i have also tried Add-Migration init -context RazorEmployeeContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the error indicates,it couldn't create an instance of RazorEmployeeContext because you didn't regist them propely in the DI container

Try regist them seperatly :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RazorlistContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorlistContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'RazorlistContext' not found.")));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RazorEmployeeContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorEmployeeContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'RazorEmployeeContext' not found.")));
```

The constructor of each  dbcontext

```
public RazorlistContext(DbContextOptions<RazorlistContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
public RazorEmployeeContext(DbContextOptions<RazorEmployeeContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
```

Comment: How can I register properly then?

Comment: I've mentioned it in my answer,have you tried to regist them seperatly?

Comment: yes, I have registered them separately as you have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Could you add migration successfully or still get the same error?in my case,i succeeded .

Comment: still getting errors also tried many methods.

Comment: I checked the codes you updated,you registed the RazorlistContext for 2 times ,check the codes in my answer and you would found the difference

Comment: thanks for the help I had created two separate context files for different tables which weren't needed now I just created the second table instance in the first DB Context and its working

Answer (score 0):

Content of the image is:

```
PM> Add-Migration init -Context RazorEmployeeContext
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'RazorEmployeeContext'. For different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
PM>
```

Here's the link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728, which currently maps to "Learn / .NET / Entity Framework / Entity Framework Core / Design-time DbContext Creation"